# If I have two output values from one function, can I use the outputs as arguments (type int) for an array?

Tags: python, function, numpy

If I have a function in Python which returns two outputs (e.g. winner and loser) that are of type int, could that output be used as an index for an array? Like G[func()[0]] (where G is a numpy matrix or an array). More specifically, if that function contains a randomly generated number, will the output value be different each time it is called? Is there a way to extract the returned values from one function call?

Comment: `x, y = func()` then use `x` and `y` however you want

Comment: Every int value should be useable for array indexing, no matter where it comes from.

Comment: You should provide context and examples, what you want to do is unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a function returns multiple values, it's actually returning a tuple. So you can certainly index it as `func()[0]` or `func()[1]` to get just one of them, since that's how you access tuple elements.

If you call it repeatedly, it will return whatever the function returns each time, which could be random. There's nothing special about calling a function as part of an expression.

The idiomatic way to extract the returned values is by using unpacking assignment:

```
winner, loser = func()
print(G[winner])
```

Comment: "*If it's random, you'll get a different random value.*" -> you **might** get, or will **probably** get  ;)